# How to include the dijit.css and other related .css files in the dojo build file

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to create a dojo build file. What do I need to add in the profile.js file to include all the .css files inside the dojo build.js file. I'm getting dijit.js and other .js files, but the dependent .css files are not getting built into the build.js file

I'm using dojo 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to ask to combine JS and CSS into a single file.  JavaScript is JavaScript; CSS is CSS.

That said, you should be able to get down to as little as one CSS request by specifying `cssOptimize: 'comments'` in your build profile, which will strip comments from CSS files within packages the build processes, and flatten imports.  As a result, each Dijit theme's main CSS file (e.g. themes/claro/claro.css) will then require only one request, rather than requests for each component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ken. Even when I tried using cssOptimize: 'comments', I don't see the css in the build.js file. I agree with you about having a separate combined .css file but I'm not even getting a unified css file. Any idea about how to generate the combined .css file or as to where it might have been saved?

Comment: The unified CSS file will be in the same relative location as the original.  So for example if your source is in `src` and your build is in `dist`, `src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css` will contain `@import` statements, while `dist/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css` will be one large file with the rules from the original `@imports` included.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken. That helped a lot.